# Liferay 6.2 GA5: error with building services

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6.2, liferay-service-builder

I'm trying to do some modification to the service layer of my portlet (e.g adding a column or a finder  to a table in the service.xml). No matter what I do, when I build services it all goes  good(no errors) but when I try to deploy or make the war, many errors appear. In this case I was just adding a new column (note2) to an already existent table

The method getNote2() is undefined for the type ESFShooterAffiliationChrono

or this:

The method getNote2() of type ESFShooterAffiliationChronoModelImpl must override or implement a supertype method

I'm working on Eclipse Luna 4.4.0, liferay IDE 3.1.2, Java JDK 1.7.0 67. I've set Compliance to 1.7 in eclipse and both "ant.build.javac.source" " ant.build.javac.target" to 1.7 in build.properties.

I think there must be something wrong with the service builder. I tried starting over with a new workspace and a fresh Plugin SDK, even with the 6.2 GA6 but with no avail. I've also tried deleting all generated service class before doing the service build but without success.

Can you give me any advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have some old code around and embedded in your dependencies. Search for a -service.jar named after your plugin, e.g. your-portlet-service.jar.

This might also happen when both a your-portlet-service.jar *and* the WEB-INF/services folder are on your build path. The compiler and the editor might pick up different versions. And when you build through Ant, Ant might pick a third variation for the precedence.

Check your eclipse *and* your Ant build path.